# First unused number in a varchar(5) field padded with zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a varchar(5) field. I need find the first unused number across all records such that they begin with leading zeros.  like if there is a 00001 and a 00003 I'd like the query to return 00002. Also, many of the records contain letters and look like 'G0542'. These can be ignored.

I know I'm close. This seems to work in SQL Server 2005 but not in 2008 or 2012

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4016a0/1

```
create table b_addr ( inst_no varchar(5) Unique );
insert into b_addr (inst_no) values ('00001');
insert into b_addr (inst_no) values ('00002');
insert into b_addr (inst_no) values ('00004');
--this is the problem line 
insert into b_addr (inst_no) values ('A0045');

With usedNos as( 
select  CAST(b_addr.inst_no AS INT) as inst 
from b_addr 
where b_addr.inst_no LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') 
SELECT 
RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), COALESCE(min(inst)+1, 0)),5) AS next_inst_no 
from usedNos where not exists (select null from usedNos usn where usn.inst = usedNos.inst +1)
```

How can I structure this so it will work in sql server 2008+ as well?

Comment: Why do you need/want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version of your query that works:

```
With usedNos as ( 
      select CAST(case when isnumeric(b_addr.inst_no) = 1
                       then b_addr.inst_no 
                  end AS INT) as inst 
      from b_addr 
     ) 
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), COALESCE(min(inst)+1, 0)),5) AS next_inst_no 
from usedNos
where inst is not null and 
      not exists (select 1
                  from usedNos usn
                  where usn.inst = usedNos.inst +1
                 );
```

The key is the use of `isnumeric()` inside of `case`.  This guarantees that the `cast()` is not attempted unless the value looks like a number.  If it doesn't look like a number, then the result is `NULL`, which is filtered out in the outer `where` clause.

Your `where` clause:

```
      where b_addr.inst_no LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

attempts to do the same thing.  However, SQL Server doesn't guarantee that the `where` clause is processed before the `select` -- which is why you are getting an unexpected error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the number you're trying to cast is a real number:

Instead of

```
CAST(b_addr.inst_no AS INT) as inst
```

Do something like

```
CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(b_addr.inst_no) = 1 THEN b_addr.inst_no ELSE 0 END AS INT) as inst
```

It's a bit convoluted, but it works.

**Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1aee5/6**

Answer (score 1):

```
create table b_addr ( inst_no varchar(5) Unique );
insert into b_addr (inst_no) values ('00001');
insert into b_addr (inst_no) values ('00002');
insert into b_addr (inst_no) values ('00004');
--this is the problem line 
insert into b_addr (inst_no) values ('A0045');

--Specify how many of the "next" unused numbers you want.
DECLARE @HowMany INT = 10

--Common Table Expression construct to generate sequential numbers.
;WITH 
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A, L3 AS B),
  L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A, L4 AS B),
  L6   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L5 AS A, L5 AS B),
  SequentialNumbers AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c) AS Num FROM L6)
SELECT TOP(@HowMany) RIGHT('00000' + CAST(sn.Num AS VARCHAR), 5) AS NextNumbers
FROM SequentialNumbers sn
WHERE sn.Num NOT IN ( 
    SELECT  CAST(b_addr.inst_no AS INT) AS inst 
    FROM b_addr 
    WHERE b_addr.inst_no LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

here's another one using `patindex` instead of like.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1aee5/12

```
With usedNos as( 
    select   b_addr.inst_no  as inst 
    from b_addr 
    where patindex('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',b_addr.inst_no) > 0
    ) 

SELECT 
RIGHT('00000' + COALESCE(cast((min(cast(inst as int)) + 1) as varchar), '00000'),5) AS next_inst_no 
from usedNos 
where not exists (select null from usedNos usn where  cast(usn.inst as int) = cast(usedNos.inst as int) + 1  )

--should return 00003, trying to find the first unused inst_no and padd it with zeros to make it 5 chars.
```

Comment: I haven't found anything definitive after a quick search, nor have I done any testing to verify the speed.